# Installing openpyxl 2.5

Tags: python, linux, openpyxl

I need to install openpyxl 2.5 on a new server.  When I run "pip3 install openpyxl" it installs 2.4.9.  There are features in 2.5 that are required for what I'm working on.

I have been able to get 2.5 on my Mac because I can download the source and simply copy/paste it where it needs to go.  However, I'm just not experienced enough in python or linux command line to use an alternate route of my own making to get 2.5 installed on a server.

Can someone give me a "recipe" or an alternative to pip3 that will install version 2.5?

Comment: what happens if you do `pip3 install openpyxl==2.5.0`?

Comment: @DeepSpace that gets me really close.  It looks like 2.5 is in beta now, but I was able to use `sudo pip3 install openpyxl==2.5.0b1` and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DeepSpace I was able to get this done by using the following because 2.5 is still in beta at the moment:

```
sudo pip3 install openpyxl==2.5.0b1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help for pip, you'll see that there is an option for installing pre-release versions: `pip install --pre openpyxl'